# Finding mean of sum where there's no definite stop

Tags: statistics, expected-value

I'm having trouble with this question:

Suppose $r$ chips are grabbed from $n$ chips where each chip is numbered $1$ to $n$. Let V be the sum of the chips. Find E(V)

What I thought of so far was the series but I don't know where to go next:

$\frac{n_1+n_2+n_3...n_n}{\text{number of n}}$

But that's it. I don't know where to go/what to do next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're told that $r$ chips are taken, so we can label the values of the chips $X_1, \ldots, X_r$ and set the sum $V = \sum_{i = 1}^r X_i$.

Then, we can take the expected value of $V$ as $E(V) = E\left(\sum_{i = 1}^r X_i\right) = \left(\sum_{i = 1}^r E(X_i)\right)$ thanks to the linearity of expectation.

Given that the chips are numbered 1 to $n$, what is $E(X_i)$?

Comment: Thank you, your description of the problem was really clear! I almost got it but I find it confusing that $E(X_i)$ is simply just $\sum^n_{i=1} i$, rather than follow the discrete pdf expected value formula of $E(X_i)\sum^n_{i=1} i*p(x) $ where $p(x) = \frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: Your expression for the expectation is correct (except you shouldn't use $i$ both to index the random variable and the sum). $E(X_i) = \sum_j j P(X_i = j) = \frac{n+1}{2}$ when you work through it all.